# Add NSMenuItems to other Apications' Menus

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I use an application called Afloat that adds a few buttons to the "Window" menu of every application that uses windows. It adds the Afloat icon and options like "Keep Afloat" which will leave the active window as the window that stays the furthest forward even if the user clicks a different window. I would like to add an item to the "Edit" menu and to all contextual menus on a text editor. I can't find how to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Quote by Apple:

> The [`CFPlugIn`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPlugInRef/Reference/reference.html) provides a standard architecture for application extensions. A contextual menu plug-in, which is `CFPlugIn` bundle installed in a `Library/Contextual Menu Items` directory at the appropriate level of the system, enables applications and other forms of software to extend the list of commands found on contextual menus such as the Finder’s.

Alternatively, you can use [Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html) to integrate with other applications.